# Which is the fastest Pokemon with regards to lore?

Tags: pokemon-series

Arcanine are said to travel 6200 miles in a day and night, which comes out to about 250mph. Dragonite are said to break the sound barrier (~750mph), and to be able to fly around the world in .. was it 15 hours? (~1500mph) They're also stated to be the fastest flying Pokemon.

Is there any more information on what speeds Pokemon reach? Either as travel speeds (would be interested in both flying, land, water, and underground), or muscle movement speed (e.g. if it could react to block an attack in a millisecond, and we know roughly how large the Pokemon is so we could guess a distance needed to block, that could give us a speed).

I couldn't find any information on Speed Deoxys, which would be a natural candidate for many records.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's only one consistent way to judge this, thanks to how infrequent good Pokedex data is.

#### In-game Stats

Arcanine has a base speed stat of 95 (Gen 6). Dragonite has a base speed stat of 80. [And travels around the world in 16 hours](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Dragonite_(Pok%C3%A9mon)#Pok.C3.A9dex_entries_2). Compared to [most Pokemon,](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_by_base_stats_(Generation_VI-present)) this is rather slow. Using this method, we can see that the fastest pokemon stat-wise are:

1. Deoxys (Speed) - 180
2. Ninjask - 160
3. Mega Alakazam - 150
4. Mega Aerodactyl - 150
5. Deoxys (Normal) - 150

So it seems Deoxys (Speed) is much faster than Arcanine. Considering most pokemon do not have detailed notes on their speed, and poke-lore is ridiculously inconsistent it seems going off in-game stats is the best way to go.

We could use the speed values to make an estimte of their actual speeds though, using the data provided about Arcanine and Dragoite

250 / 95 = 2.63mph per base speed

40,075 (Distance around the world) / 16 hours = 1556.25mph.
/ 80 = 19.45mph per base speed

Our first calculation would give Speed Deoxys (2.63 * 180) = 473.4mph, while our second would give them (19.45 * 180) 3501mph. That would cover the distance of New York to LA in one hour.

#### In Lore

The Pokemon lore is inconsistent, contradictory, and quite useless, but I shall append some answer to this.

- Genesect using Extreme-Speed - Quite fast - but no numbers
- Latios - "Faster than a jet" ((1,555 mph, 2,503 km/h))
- Pidgeot - Mach 2 speed 2,447 km/h
- [Golduck](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Golduck_(Pok%C3%A9mon)#Pok.C3.A9dex_entries_2) - Explicitly stated to be the fastest swimmer
- Ninjask - Moves so fast they are almost Invisible.
  Using information from [here](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=580044), they must move at around 20,000km/h minimum, and from a distance of 10 miles (which is the distance to view the object for it to seem invisible). This is almost impossible from a close distance (If it abides by normal laws of physics, it'd be almost impossible to move so fast as to be almost invisible at a close distance. But if the Dex is to be believed, this is without a doubt the fastest pokemon.)

Comment: The ingame speed stat rather represents agility than travel speed. Also, the question explicitly asked for *lore* information, not an answer based on game data.

Comment: @arda There's plenty of in-game lore, which could be used in an answer here. There are numerous Pokédex entries for most Pokémon, and tons of other information that can be found in the game from characters and libraries.

Comment: @Samthere If we're talking Official Documentation (IE: Pokedex Entries and demonstrations in Anime) there is very little to be mentioned on speed. And the series contradicts itself constantly with pokedex entries ETC. Speed stats are the best way to determine the fastest pokemon. It's almost certainly speed Deoxys, but there's no numbers on it, as the lore is incredibly lacking.

Comment: @BritishFerret I don't disagree with your approach, but when the question is specifically about the in-game lore then the stats aren't the deciding factor. It _may_ be a bad question, or take an unreasonable amount of effort to answer, but that doesn't make a stat-reliant answer correct in this particular context.

Comment: Data from the pokedex has been used. The problem is that it frequently contradicts itself. It's hardly a lore to be taken seriously. However, it seems Ninjask must be the fastest pokemon.

Comment: Ninjask's feat is actually commonplace in the Pokémon universe. Quick Attack's description reads "The user lunges at the target at a speed that makes it almost invisible". Quick Attack users include Trapinch, which has a Base Speed of 10. **Pokémon lore is nonsense**.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Kind of makes this question moot. If everyone can move to the point of being nearly invisible (which with our physics, or unless everyone in the pokemon world has terrible eyesight) requires a ridiculously high speed to move at. Considering there's no consistency to these physics, there's no point using lore information. Stat numbers are the only way to get a solid answer to this question.

Comment: Thanks! I realize there are many inconsistencies in the Pokédex, but this is exactly the kind of answer I was hoping for. Figures I found online say things become invisible (due to being too small) at ratios like 1m/5km, or 0.3m/1km. Given Ninjask's height of 0.8m, I would not expect one to be visible at more than 4km, which reduces the speed proportionally (still ridiculous, though)! I'd also like to point out that in the same post they discuss how the appropriate speed at close range (although you have to add angular width to fovea) and quick attack could potentially have reasonable numbers.

Comment: I think all Pokemon who learn the move Double Team can be "fast enough to be invisible"; in fact, they can be fast enough to be invisible in some places, and visible in more than one place simultaneously. Scyther is impressive like that in the anime.

Answer (score 3):

The question is unanswerable.

Pokémon lore, especially move and Pokédex description, has always been very exaggerated since it's supposed to appeal to children. There has never been any proof that the grandest claims found in the Pokédex are true. For example:

> Magcargo's body temperature is approximately 18,000 degrees Fahrenheit.

You'd burst into flames if you so much as looked at one.

> Alakazam's brain continually grows, infinitely multiplying brain cells.

Alakazam's head has yet to explode.

> [Machamp's] four ruggedly developed arms can launch a flurry of 1,000 punches in just two seconds.

125 punches per arm per second.

> Manectric is constantly discharging electricity from its mane. The sparks sometimes ignite forest fires. When it enters a battle, this Pokémon creates thunderclouds.

Manectric does not, in fact, create thunderclouds or discharge constantly.

> [Cubone] always wears the skull of its dead mother, so no one has any idea what its hidden face looks like.

I've bred Cubone before, and my Marowak still has a skull, and is definitely alive.

> When [Victini] shares the infinite energy it creates, that being's entire body will be overflowing with power.

We've got a being that can produce infinite energy. Not a huge amount, not enough to obliterate the universe, it's literally infinite. I don't need to tell you how ridiculous that is. If any Pokémon is the fastest, it's Victini.

And finally, Quick Attack's description:

> The user lunges at the target at a speed that makes it almost invisible.

I guess anything that learns Quick Attack is the fastest Pokémon in existence, if you want to trust the lore, but I prefer [this move](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Teleport_(move)).

Comment: Note that "infinite" is often used (wrongly) as a synonymous for "unbounded". In other words, "infinitely renewable". That doesn't necessarily mean Victini can produce infinite [power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_(physics)), but maybe that it can produce energy continuously for an infinitely long time. Imagine if I say I have a "tap producing infinite water" in the bathroom of my magical mansion; I don't mean that the tap has infinite flow rate and can instantaneously produce an infinite volume of water; I simply mean that the tap never runs out of water.

Answer (score 1):

According to Gary in the original TV series it would be Diglett.

> > "Diglett can pull their heads into the ground at the speed of light!"

Pretty sure that will top any other stat!!

[Source](http://aileran.tumblr.com/post/19227024915/episode-31-dig-those-diglett)

Comment: Can you provide a source for this quote? I tried to find one but could not. I assume it's from EP031?

Comment: @Vemonus, http://aileran.tumblr.com/post/19227024915/episode-31-dig-those-diglett

Comment: I don't know how trustworthy of a source Gary Oak can be. Not to mention it's the anime.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer, the question only asked for the fastest pokemon according to lore.. If Gary Oak heard it from someone who heard it from someone then it becomes lore

Comment: @c.pullen You've got a nice big "if" there, and anime lore is not game lore.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer, you're right, it is a pretty big if. but that's what makes lore so fun, most of the other answers (apart from the base stat answers) are also from the anime, pokemon lore is pokemon lore...

Comment: @c.pullen If you're not sure something is lore, you can't call it lore. And no, anime lore and game lore are absolutely not the same thing.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer, Lore: "a body of traditions and knowledge on a subject or held by a particular group, typically passed from person to person by word of mouth." from the oxford dictionary. as gary heard that they can move this fast then it is lore by definition.

Comment: Look, if you're not reading what I'm saying, just don't bother replying. This is getting way too long for comments anyway, and I've said everything I needed to say.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer, the answer was only meant to be a bit of fun, and it is in my answer that this was from the anime, not the game.

Comment: I'm watching the pokemon anime again (more thoroughly) and when this scene came up I was immediately reminded of this answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Garchomp is said to fly as fast as a fighter jet and an average fighter jest can go 4000 km/h while Dragonite can only go 2505 km/h. Zeraora can go as fast as lightning but a lightning bolt's speed is less than 2000 km/h.

Comment: I'm not sure where you go the lightning figure, but lightning is much faster than that. Although giving it a precise speed seems complicated: the downward bolt is about 1000x times slower than the upward. Various sites seem to support the statement that downward lighting is ~200,000km/h, and the upward is something ~100,000,000km/h, a sizable fraction of the speed of light.

Comment: These sources seem reputable: https://web.archive.org/web/20170210085959/https://www.ucar.edu/communications/factsheets/Lightning.html and https://www.wired.com/2010/02/gallery-lightning/

By these figures, I think Zeraora blows everything else here out of the water! Except for Diglett, of course, and anything using Teleport. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hoothoot-It always stands on one foot. It changes feet so fast, the movement can rarely be seen.

```
                                                   -Pokemon Sword Pokedex
```

Comment: It seems like he changes his feet so fast you only see one at a time, but it isn't a particularly fast Pokémon in the sense that it can transverse distances quickly.